# Raising an error if a dict value has more than specified number of digits

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to raise an error if a value in a dict has greater than e.g. 6 digits (would be useful to test for a particular number of decimal places too).

e.g. for the dict below (and say number digits = 6)

```
example_dict = {'dict_id': 12345,
                 'key1': 10501.04999999999999999262}
for key, value in tariff_detail.items():
    if value == type(float) and (test for number of digits):
        raise ValueError("DictID: {}, Key Missing: {}".format(example_dict['dict_id'],key))
```

(Note if I stick the above example in ipython and do example_dict.values() it pops out [10501.05]  - Is there in built rounding or is this just for display?)

What's the best way to test for the number of digits and raise an error on fail?

Comment: Floating point values are [stored in base 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  They don't have decimal digits as such.  Maybe you wanted [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) instead?

Comment: Do you know http://floating-point-gui.de/ and the classic `0.1+0.2 = 0.30000000000000004`?

Comment: 10501.05 has no exact floating point representation, while 12345 have one.  perharps another representation (price in cents for exemple) will be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is to convert the value to a string then count its length:

```
if len(str(value)) > 6 :
```

Comment: I did think of that one - doesn't feel too pythonic though- is there a better way as I'm sure this is a common problem?

Comment: @Yunti Part of the problem is distinguishing between meaningful digits and digits. You might consider using the `round` function or the `decimal` module.

Comment: If you need decimal digits (after «.») you can `split('.')` number by `dot` then count second element `len(str(value).split('.')[1])`